# Force Flash Player instead of HTML5 Player Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, video, flash, html5

There are certain media websites  for example :

www.ytpak.com

www.djmaza.com

which when I try to play the Video/Audio in Google Chrome Version 46.0.2490.71 m (64-bit) installed Windows 10 HTML5 Player loads instead of website's original flash player, which is really annoying due to less control and other features.

However, when I load  the same websites in FireFox 41.0.1 , the website's original player works fine.

I've downloaded and installed latest Flash Player and enabled it in Google Chrome .

Comment: How is the Flash Player plug-in in Chrome even still working considering it was the flag that enabled it was due to be removed in Chrome 46?

Comment: I enabled it in the plugins. I will post the details below

Comment: Adobe Flash Player - Version: 19.0.0.207
Shockwave Flash 19.0 r0
Name: Shockwave Flash
Description: Shockwave Flash 19.0 r0
Version: 19.0.0.207
Location: C:\Program Files (x86)\Google\Chrome\Application\46.0.2490.71\PepperFlash\pepflashplayer.dll
Type: PPAPI (out-of-process)

Answer (score 0):

it's best you switch over to firefox. I am facing issues with chrome and HTML5 plugin , there are 2 things i have noticed - a) audio issues wherein audio is quite feeble b) video issues - videos even though get buffered tend to get stuck and out  of sync  with audio.